# Matching ASN.1 string with python regexp

Tags: python, regex, asn.1

How can I match this ASN.1 string with python regexp

```
"::= { bgpPathAttrEntry 6 }"
```

I try this regexp:

```
\s+::=\s*{\s*(?P<entry>\S+\s\d+)}\n
```

and fail.

Comment: the regexp i use is : \n\s+::=\s*{\s*(?P<entry>\S+\s\d+)}\n

Comment: Try `::=\s*{\s*(?P<entry>[^{}]*?)\s*}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC2r1j/2).

Comment: Change the leading `\s+` to `\s*` and add `\s*` before the `}` like `\s*::=\s*{\s*(?P<entry>\S+\s\d+)\s*}` https://regex101.com/r/0zEXiT/1

Comment: THANK's a lot Viktor  ! it's OK NOW !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
::=\s*{\s*(?P<entry>[^{}]*?)\s*}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC2r1j/2)

**Details**

- `::=` - a literal substring
- `\s*{\s*` - a `{` char enclosed with zero or more whitespace chars
- `(?P<entry>[^{}]*?)` - Group "entry": any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`, but as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `}` - a `}` char.